# Error show dusrin npm build on server upload files

Tags: npm

[eslint] package.json » eslint-config-wesbos:
Configuration for rule "no-unused-vars" is invalid:
Value {"ignoreSiblings":true,"argsIgnorePattern":"res|next|^err"} should be equal to one of the allowed values.
Value {"ignoreSiblings":true,"argsIgnorePattern":"res|next|^err"} should NOT have additional properties.
Value {"ignoreSiblings":true,"argsIgnorePattern":"res|next|^err"} should match exactly one schema in oneOf.